# Windows 10 resets taskbar height to single row after restart

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I set my taskbar to auto-hide and a height of two rows of icons/buttons. But each time I restart the PC the height is reset to one row. (Auto-hide is preserved.)
On another computer running the same Windows build (10.0.15063) the two row height is preserved between restarts.

Is there a fix for this, registry or otherwise? I already checked "Taskbar settings", but to no avail.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you perform a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows)?

Comment: Give this script a try.. [Completely Reset the Taskbar Settings to Defaults](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/reset-taskbar-settings-to-defaults/). And then customize the taskbar again.

Comment: (1) What happens if the taskbar is not set to hide? (2) Try to set it to 3 rows and reboot (sometimes it then stays as 2 rows). (3) With taskbar set to 2 rows, use Group Policy Editor to navigate to *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Task Bar* and enable *Lock all Taskbar settings*.

Answer (score 8):

This is a well-known problem that has hit many people in all versions of
Windows. Some workarounds that worked for some people are listed below:

1. Some say that when the taskbar auto-hide is the cause of the problem,
   and that setting it to off fixes it. Sounds reasonable, but not what you are
   looking for.
2. Others claim that setting the taskbar height to 3 rows and rebooting
   makes it stay as 2 rows. Strange, but maybe worth trying.
3. Another advice is to set the taskbar to 2 rows,
   then use Group Policy Editor to navigate to
   *User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Task Bar*
   and enable *Lock all Taskbar settings*. This one looks like the best bet.

For Windows Home, the above can be done using regedit to navigate to the key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
and create a DWORD entry named `TaskbarLockAll` with the value of `1`.

Comment: I've tried "setting the taskbar height to 3 rows and rebooting [to make] it stay as 2 rows," but that did not work from me. Using the GPE is not an option for Windows 10 Home, but I'll try the equivalent Registry key for "Lock all Taskbar settings": http://www.thewindowsclub.com/lock-all-taskbar-settings

Comment: The Registry hack suggested by GPE worked! This is accepted.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I have added this registry edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Adding Regedit scripts setting the DWORD to 1 and to 0 allows for quick locking and unlocking.

Comment: The option 2 (set to three rows) worked... one time. After next reset it went down to one haha

Answer (score 1):

My taskbar height kept reducing with each restart until it was a single bar in height.  Strangely enough the taskbar was locked after resizing and this happened.  However, if you leave the taskbar unlocked after resizing it retained the intended height, go figure!  Just size it and leave it unlocked. Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the clean reboot, I hid all the Microsoft services and disabled the other services on the PC until I was able to isolate the service that was resetting the taskbar back to 1 line. On my PC it was the  "Intel(R) HD Graphics Control Panel Service". By disabling this service I can set my taskbar to any size and it will be maintained across system restarts.  It does not matter if the taskbar is locked or not before the reboot. The size of the taskbar remains the same as the last setting.

This was a brand new install of Windows 10-Pro 64 bit that had all the latest updates applied (As of July 18,2019).  Motherboard was an ASUS Z87-Pro motherboard with Intel Z87 Express Chipset.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem appears to be with a McAfee security program. Last year I got the program with an internet subscription and the problem started. After deleting the program, the problem went away. Yesterday I got the McAfee again through a Spectrum service and the problem popped back up. I will be deleting the program and am sure that the problem will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short AutoHotKey script that I save to my Desktop, then run after each reboot. Of course, you need to have AutoHotKey installed and there are many YouTube videos that can help with this.  The script is tailored to my particular resolution and settings and you'll probably need to adjust the Y position numbers (1080, 1022, and 945) to suit your situation.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
MouseMove, 1000, 1080, 20
Sleep, 20
MouseMove, 1000, 1022, 20
Sleep 20
MouseClickDrag, Left, 1000, 1022, 1000, 945, 20
Exit
```